# Can JMS Durable Subscribers be grouped for HA?

Tags: java, jms

I'm wondering if the following is possible with any JMS broker.

We have N instances of a service that run in a clustered mode. Each instance has a JMS durable subscriber which handles business events from a topic.

The question is: Is it possible to configure those subscribers so only one of them will receive an event? (basically, that the group of durable subscribers behave as if they were consuming from a queue).

I know that this is possible with queues, but we have many different services (all clustered) listening to several business events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question is JMS2, as it has a new feature called *shared durable subscriptions* that allows durable subscriptions to be shared between several JVMs.

More info in [What's new in JMS2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms2messaging-1954190.html) (search for *Shared durable subscriptions*).

Comment: Yes, Indeed JMS 2.0 has load balancing across subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps...

For our project which is a clustered environment with nodes say (N1,N2,N3) and we wanted that specific JMS messages should be serviced by a specific MDB Queue(in your case subscribers), we did the following:

```
A. Create two MDB queue MDB1 and MDB2.
B. Used `MDBNotificationListenerMBean` to stop MDB1 on N2
C. Used `MDBNotificationListenerMBean` to stop MDB2 on N1 & N3.
```

and posted messages to different queues...

Now MDB1 is available on N1 & N3 and MDB2 only listens to messages on N2.

Comment: Hi Bhrath, one of the reasons I want to do this is to avoid having any routing logic in the applications. Quite often, we have 5-7 applications listening to the same business event, and each application has several nodes. So as you can imagine, we have hundreds of queues and it's becoming a bit unmanageable.

Answer (score 0):

I am curios, you mention multiple instance of the same application run on multiple nodes, those instanced will be communicating with the same broker right? If so, all instances can share the same JMS queue for processing business events. In such case, large number of queues are not required. You can have one queue for all instances of an application. Do you see any issues with this approach?

At this time, no broker implementations provide the behavior you are looking for.